# Entity Framework Null reference exception when adding to bridge tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework with an MVC5 Application and currently I am trying to save some form data that touches multiple tables in my database. When I am adding data to the tables it seems to be working fine but once I hit the bridge tables I am getting a null ref exception that, to me, doesn't make sense.

I am new to programming so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public void RegisterNewUser(IDCRegisterViewModel model)
    {
        //
        string fullAddress = model.AddressLine1 + "\n" + model.AddressLine2 + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.AddressLine2) ? "" : "\n" ) + model.City + ", " + model.State + " " + model.Zip + "\n" + model.Country; 
        using (var AuthContext = new InfoKeeperEntities1())
        {
            AuthContext.Locations.Add(new Location {
                Line1 = model.AddressLine1,
                Line2 = model.AddressLine2,
                City = model.City,
                State = model.State,
                Zip = model.Zip,
                Country = model.Country,
                UserID = model.UserID,
                FullAddr = fullAddress
            });

            AuthContext.ProfileDatas.Add(new ProfileData
            {
                UserID = model.UserID,
                UACC = model.UACC,
                isRecCenter = model.IsRecCenter,
                isCustAdmin = model.IsCustAdmin
            });

            //Add to bridge tables for user/dept and group/dept
            List<Department> deptList = new List<Department>();
            foreach (var ID in model.GroupIDs)
            {
                deptList.Add(AuthContext.Departments.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == ID));
            }

            foreach (var department in deptList)
            {
                //NULL REF EXCEPTION HERE
                AuthContext.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.UserID).Departments.Add(department);

                foreach (var groupID in model.GroupIDs)
                {
                    AuthContext.Groups.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == groupID).Departments.Add(department);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please indicate which line is throwing the null reference exception.

Comment: Updated. Thank you.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your code on the line where you have the NULL REF, and when it hits the breakpoint, highlight this portion of the line AuthContext.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.UserID) , right click and select quick watch to see if this LINQ statement returns anything.

Comment: The line:

    AuthContext.Departments.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == ID)

can return nulls, and also this line: AuthContext.Groups.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == groupID)

Comment: The model.ID was actually the Username. I fixed it and now the null reference exception is fixed.. I now have a new error to deal with though... So goes coding... lol. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you turn the `LazyLoadingEnabled` and `ProxyCreationEnabled` off you always face with an error because of using `Department` after `FirstorDefault` Query and `EntityFramework` doesn't include it for AppUsers, You have the same problem with adding the department to the Group. So you must include the Department first for both of them.

put `using System.Data.Entity;` in the very first of the codes.
change the code statement to this:

```
public void RegisterNewUser(IDCRegisterViewModel model)
{
    string fullAddress = model.AddressLine1 + "\n" + model.AddressLine2 + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.AddressLine2) ? "" : "\n" ) + model.City + ", " + model.State + " " + model.Zip + "\n" + model.Country; 
    using (var AuthContext = new InfoKeeperEntities1())
    {
        AuthContext.Locations.Add(new Location {
            Line1 = model.AddressLine1,
            Line2 = model.AddressLine2,
            City = model.City,
            State = model.State,
            Zip = model.Zip,
            Country = model.Country,
            UserID = model.UserID,
            FullAddr = fullAddress
        });

        AuthContext.ProfileDatas.Add(new ProfileData
        {
            UserID = model.UserID,
            UACC = model.UACC,
            isRecCenter = model.IsRecCenter,
            isCustAdmin = model.IsCustAdmin
        });

        //Add to bridge tables for user/dept and group/dept
        List<Department> deptList = new List<Department>();
        foreach (var ID in model.GroupIDs)
        {
            deptList.Add(AuthContext.Departments.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == ID));
        }
        var user = AuthContext.AspNetUsers.Include("Departments").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.UserID);         
        foreach (var department in deptList)
        {
            user.Departments.Add(department);

            foreach (var groupID in model.GroupIDs)
            {
                var group = AuthContext.Groups.Include("Departments").FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == groupID);
                group.Departments.Add(department);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tip: Don't forget to make a new instance of `List<Depatment>` in the constructor of `AspNetUsers` and `Groups`:

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    Public ApplicationUser()
    {
        this.Departments = new List<Department>();
    }
}
public class Group
{
    Public Group()
    {
        this.Departments = new List<Department>();
    }
}
```

Comment: @SentOnLine would you like to consider it? I've updated!